# drop database, then create database results in SQL syntax error

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a homework assignment for an intro to databases class. We were given a script to use as our database. Here are the first few lines:

```
DROP DATABASE hw4;
CREATE DATABASE hw4;

use hw4;

CREATE TABLE Building(
bid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(100),
street varchar(100),
city varchar(50),
zipcode char(5),
state char(2),
PRIMARY KEY(bid)
);
```

When trying to run this, I end up with a syntax error on this line: `CREATE DATABASE hw4;`

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? I don't know much SQL at all and unfortunately the professor is making us use this script. If it makes a difference I'm trying to run this on windows 7 with MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Try inserting a "COMMIT" statement between the drop and commit.

Comment: It says that it is not valid at this position.. but the CREATE error goes away. so I'm guessing it has to do with line 2? :|

Comment: unless you are as root user every database needs an associated user for accessing it and then creating tables there.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I believe I am accessing it as a root user, since I connected initially to that user from MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 1):

You may be given an error because you are trying to drop database that doesen't exist. Try to replace first line with

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS hw4;
```

Comment: After commenting it out, running it, and commenting back in, the syntax error has moved down to the `CREATE` part of `CREATE TABLE Building (`

Comment: Try changing database name to new unique and executing the whole code once again. I wonder if error will occur in that case

Comment: After doing that, I now get: `Syntax error: ';' (identifier) is not valid input at this position.` The error now comes from here: `USE hw4unique;` and the DROP/CREATE have been renamed to `hw4unique` as well.

Comment: Try removing `Use dbname;` statement and instead prefix all tablenames with it, like so: `CREATE TABLE hw4.Building(...` . Of course, make sure db exists.